# KMeans with Spark 1.6.2 VS Spark 2.0.0

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, k-means, apache-spark-1.6, apache-spark-2.0

I am using `Kmeans()` in an environment I have no control and I will abandon in <1 month. Spark 1.6.2. is installed.

Should I pay the price for urging 'them' to upgrade to Spark 2.0.0 before I leave? In other words, does Spark 2.0.0 introduce any **significant improvements** when it comes to *Spark Mllib KMeans()*?

In my case, quality is a more important factor than speed.

Comment: _Highly opinionated and untested answer_: Highly unlikely. There is nothing in 2.0 that could significantly improved KMeans performance and implementation didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather unlikely.

Spark 2.0.0 doesn't introduce [any significant improvements to the core RDD API](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html) and `KMeans` implementation [didn't change much since 1.6](https://github.com/apache/spark/commits/a6290e51e402e8434d6207d553db1f551e714fde/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeans.scala) with relatively significant changes introduced only by [SPARK-15322](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15322), [SPARK-16696](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16696) and [SPARK-16694](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16694).

If you use ML API there can be also some improvements related to [SPARK-14850](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14850) but overall I don't see any game changers here.